# Force MapStruct to use custom method instead of dto value

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a UserDTO and User entity which I want to map. When creating a new User some fields (for example: `password`, `modifiedBy`) must be generated by some custom method (for example: `password` is randomly generated and encoded, but `modifiedBy` username is retrieved from security service). For this I autowire some services into the mapper. Many of them return `String` and MapStruct cannot understand which one to use in each case and just uses the first it found on everything that accepts `String` as input.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PasswordEncoder.class)
public interface UserMapper {

@Mapping(target = "password", qualifiedByName = "PASS")
User mapUser(UserDto dto);

@Named("PASS")
default String getPass(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
    return passwordEncoder.encode(some_random_generator);
    }
}
```

This generates code that just uses method from `PasswordEncoder` in any setter that accepts `String` and `getPass(...)` method is not used at all.
However I need it to use my `getPass(...)` method on `password` field only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to pass the used mapper or service to a default method. There is [mapstruct/mapstruct#1637](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1637) open for that. Also you can't really do `@Mapper( uses = PasswordEncoder.class )` as that would lead to all `String` to `String` to be mapped via the `PasswordEncoder`. What you can do though is to create your own custom `PasswordEncoderMapper` and use `@Named` on it, this way you would be in control.

This can look like this:

```
@Qualifier // org.mapstruct.Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface EncodedMapping {
}

public class PasswordEncoderMapper {

    protected final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public PasswordEncoderMapper(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @EncodedMapping
    public String encode(String value) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(value);
    }
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PasswordEncoderMapper.class)
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "password", qualifiedBy = EncodedMapping.class)
    User mapUser(UserDto dto);
}
```

Regarding the `modifiedBy` property. You should do that as part of an `@ObjectFactory` or by using an expression.

With an expression this can look like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PasswordEncoderMapper.class, imports = SecurityUtils.class)
public interface UserMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "password", qualifiedBy = EncodedMapping.class)
    @Mapping(target = "modifiedBy", expression = "java(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserId())")
    User mapUser(UserDto dto);
}
```

Comment: This still applies in 2023! Thank you! I'm using Spring Boot, so I needed to annotate the class you named PasswordEncoderMapper with @Component.